# Simple git-tfs unshelve kicking back "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: git-tfs, unshelve

I have quite a bit of work in a TFS shelveset and wanted to switch to using git-tfs. Things started smoothly, but I'm stuck on the error below. Here was my sequence, working from an empty directory.

```
> git-tfs quick-clone http://my-server/tfs/collection $/my/tfs/path
3145 objects created...
blah = longhashcode

> cd path

> git checkout -b MyWork
Switched to new branch 'MyWork'

> git-tfs unshelve MyTfsShelfName MyWork
The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've tried adding -u "myuser", a new branch name, etc., but can't get any farther than "The system cannot find the file specified." Stumped. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the error message you're getting is caused by git-tfs not being able to locate git.exe. (It is git.cmd that is added to the path by default). Instead of "git-tfs", try using "git tfs", like so:

```
git tfs unshelve MyTfsShelfName MyWork
```

More information: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/31